# Nested For Loop Parallel with global dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to make this block of code run in parallel.

Currently it is running at about 6 minutes per model which is way too slow.

```
d_mtry={}
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
pass; count = 0; itr = COUNT
while count < itr
    kf = KFold(n_splits = 10)
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------
    for j in range (2, 25):
        avg_acc = 0
        for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_train):
            X_train_K, X_test_K = X_train[train_index], X_train[test_index]
            y_train_K, y_test_K = y_train[train_index], y_train[test_index]
            rotf = RRForestClassifier( n_estimators = 30,
                                       criterion    =  'entropy',
                                       max_features =  j,
                                       n_jobs       = -1,
                                       random_state =  1
                                       )
            rotf.fit(X_train_K, y_train_K)

            y_predict_K = rotf.predict(X_test_K)
            y_prob = rotf.predict_proba(X_test_K)

            acc_score = accuracy_score(y_test_K, y_predict_K)
            avg_acc += acc_score

        d_mtry[str(j)] = avg_acc/10

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------
    best_mtry = max(d_mtry.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

    f.write("\n" + "Iteration: " + str(count+1) + " Best M_Try: " + str(best_mtry)+ "\n")
    f.write(str(d_mtry))

    rotf = RRForestClassifier( n_estimators = 30,
                               criterion    =  'entropy',
                               max_features =  int( best_mtry ),
                               n_jobs       = -1,
                               random_state =  1
                               )
    # there is more code after this
    # I don't think it is relevant,
    # it has to do with calculations on the model rotf
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------
    count += 1
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The main issue I've been having is that the dictionary doesn't update properly in parallel for the attempts I've made. It also didn't seem to run much faster when doing a method using **`multiprocessing.Pool()`** instance, I found in another post.

The goal here is to find the best value for **`j`** ( for `max_features` class-instance attribute ), based on the average accuracy over the folds and use that when I create my model and run it on the test set.

Originally, I tried to use `GridSearchCV()`, but that ran into an issue on fitting and never finished running, even on AWS-hosted setup, there having 36 cores.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love python for the ease of prototyping.
I also know, when it comes the time to change architecture-design priorities for ultimate performance.

---

### Fact #1: `n_jobs == -1` actually occupies all the CPU-cores

This said, there are no free CPU-resources ( and you may belong to those kids of the Fortune, if not also headbanging into the `[SPACE]`-dimension of the Hardware-constraints ( yes, speaking about in-RAM computing, later translated into `[TIME]`-dimension, once your model stopped to fit in-RAM and performance will jump many orders of magnitude worse ) during intensive ML-model tuning ).

In cases, where there are no spare resources available, any process-scheduling will resort to either a pure-[`[SERIAL]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info) system-scheduling ( going one after another ) or at maximum to a "just"-[`[CONCURRENT]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info)  system-scheduling, when actual blocks-of-execution are interleaved, by an O/S system-scheduler, onto a restricted ( in size ) subset of CPU-resources, because no other "free" CPU-core is not available to do any better.

In this very case none of the tools available to Python code from the `multiprocessing` module will ever improve the code-execution performance, but the very contrary ( might have already benchmarked this or have just felt this in your own shoes ).

None of the both above named system-scheduling policies are the true-[`[PARALLEL]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info) system-scheduling examples.

---

### Fact #2: "just"-[`[CONCURRENT]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info) helps I/O-bound, not CPU-bound cases

Except for the initial DataSET loading into RAM, there is no other I/O-related performance blocking. So, any "increased" ( also any `multiprocessing` module tools' injected ) concurrency will never improve your  localhost processing throughput ( no I/O-latency masking appears to be better, than lost performance on increased CPU job-schedule interleaving and context-switching costs ).

---

### SOLUTION: If in a need for an indeed increased prototyping throughput

Having prototyped an AI/ML-prototyping factory, running almost a 24/7/365 BAU, this may help you either.

Think of a different architecture, than making a `dict` globally accessible.

The process-flow can be orchestrated:

A host_00 being a "parameter-server", telling others what `[ aMlMODEL, aParamSET, DataSET ]`

A host_01 being a "worker-pool-member", running on full steam, having `n_jobs = -1`
A host_02 being a "worker-pool-member", running on full steam, having `n_jobs = -1`
A host_03 being a "worker-pool-member", running on full steam, having `n_jobs = -1`
..
A host_NN being a "worker-pool-member", running on full steam, having `n_jobs = -1`

Having this prototyping Factory concept:
- the throughput is at max,
- the throughput is possible to get dynamically extended ( overnight et al ),
- the throughput is almost at linear scale proportional to N
- the Factory architecture has [lowest possible orchestration overheads, compared to any other naive attempts to "parallelise-a-code"](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)